# Uploading and saving picture on parse.com database for a user - Ruby on Rails website

Tags: parse-platform

I am very newbie to parse.com and REST API.
I have a website with its database on parse.com

I would like to allow user to upload a profile picture, which then is stored in parse.com database for the user.
I take a look at its REST API: https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#files

But I don't quite understand how I can integrate it with ruby on rails to allow user to upload his/her picture.

I would really appreciate if someone could help.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Check our http://github.com/adelevie/parse-resource or http://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client for help getting started with Parse + Ruby.